# User defined http status code on Google App Engine

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, http-status-codes

I have the following handler that gets the content from the received request:

```
class DummyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:
             msg = cgi.escape(self.request.get('content'))
             if msg is None:
                raise IllegalContent
        except IllegalContent as ex:
            logging.error("Illegal content received")
            self.error(RequestErrorCodes.ILLEGAL_CONTENT)
        except Exception as ex:
            logging.error(ex) 
            self.error(RequestErrorCodes.UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
```

When I run the unittest, I get the following error:

```
    self.error(RequestErrorCodes.UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 582, in error
    self.response.status = code
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I need to define user specific error codes in the http response for my client to handle. Is this supported in Google App Engine?

Comment: I would think of some other way to do it then adding status codes... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/31nUoBSGSao

Comment: As Nix suggests, inventing your own status codes is a bad idea. Don't conflate transport and application - convey your error information in the response body.